# Packet Sniffer for Android phones using VPN services

Tags: java

I'm sorry that my question looks non technical or no sense. But I need to ask with no option.

I am doing project for my degree and I have been asked to design a "Packet Sniffer for Android Phones" which should work on non rooted phones, which can not only sniff but should read those IP packets. I am new to this feild and am not such a developer. Based on my studies, i found out that packet sniffers can be developed using VPN services in android, but i dont kno to which extent this is true. Please help with this where to and how to start ??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture&hl=en).  It should meet your requirements, if your Android device is using Ice Cream Sandwich or newer.  I can't tell you how well it works because I'm on Gingerbread.  I haven't seen any other packet capture apps for Android that do not require root.